# Alternative to using $_SESSION variables to solve multiple tab issue

Tags: php, session, tabs, navigation

I started writing a web application that stores certain user information in the `$_SESSION` variable. Usual stuff - user_id, username etc.

I then started using the variables to store certain navigation information. For instance, `$_SESSION['organisation_id']` so that wherever the user is in the application, I can easily add 'organisation_id' to any table without having to parse 'organisation_id' across every page request (eg. index.php?organisation_id=456&var2=6 or anotherpage.php?organisation_id=456& etc)

All hunky dory until a user opens a new tab and starts navigating to another organisation so hence creating a new `$_SESSION['organisation_id']` value and creating an epic fail on the original tab.

The only solution I can think of is to go back to putting organisation_id into every form and navigation element within the application but yeesh, I'm thinking there must be a more elegant solution.

Normally, I find everything I need on StackOverflow but the answer to this question still eludes me!

Comment: If you move into another tab whether page load occurs or everything happens in Jquery/JS?

Answer (score 0):

"The only solution i can think of is to go back to putting organisation_id into every form and navigation element within the application but yeesh, i'm thinking there must be a more elegant solution."

No there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check if $_SESSION['organisation_id'] exist, and if so you can write new variable in session with different name, and so one.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to solve the problem. But to avoid a similar task in the future, I would suggest split up all your files into different includes. 
So even if you have to add a couple of variables to the entire site, you could modify 1 file and get it done than doing the whole thing again.

Comment: That's pretty much what we have so its not a major deal to do this. But the app uses a lot of ajax so it was pretty neat to call on the session variable without having to add to every GET. Neat - but flawed :-/

Comment: I understand the frustration of missing out on a session variable and having to do the same thing again and again. 

I dont quite get the reference of passing the session variable via a GET query though..

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a logic problem. The session represents a **state** for the user. This is because HTTP is a stateless protocol in it's essence (it don't know who is who, just undersdants requests and responses).

So the `organization_id` is a **state**. If a user can login to just one organization, you just store this in the session var like you did and use it. If the user logs out and in again with another `organization_id`, it makes sense that only the last one remain available.

If your application has to support multiple `organization_id`'s, you should reflect that logic in your session handling, saving an array of organization ids for instance (instead of just one). But then you have to change your application to allow the user to navigate from organization to organization, etc. There's no point in letting the user be in two organizations at once if the screen just shows one of them.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the value into session during onblur of that username, etc and you can get it before you clicking the next tab

(i.e) using Jquery/Javascript u can get that value of username, etc while onblur and store it in session.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by simply moving the data you currently put into the `$_SESSION` array into a sub-array within `$_SESSION`, so that you can store multiple sets of data at once in the session.

It would end up looking a bit like this:

```
$_SESSION[organisations] = array(
     '456' => array('organisationID'=>456, 'otherdata'=>'blah'),
     '678' => array('organisationID'=>678, 'otherdata'=>'blah'),
     ...etc...
);
```

This will allow you to keep the data for multiple orgs in the session data at once, so you don't have to load all the data every time.

But yes, you *will* need to send the relevant organisationID with every request, so that your code knows which element of the session data to work with. You can't really work around that. Every request will need tell PHP which orgID to work with.

The down-sides here are that by storing all that data in the session, you're using a lot more memory for your session data, so if there's a chance that the user will browse a lot of organisations during a session, I would advise limiting the size of `$_SESSION` by dropping data that hasn't been used for a while.

The other down-side is that if this is a multi-user system, storing the data in session means that it will be unaware of any updates made by other users. If you were to load the data fresh from the database on every request, yes it would create more work for the DB, but it would ensure that the data given to the user was always up-to-date.